# How can I have bended text as arc data in wheelchart coming from a variable?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to have some text on top (or at any side) of the circle which could work as a title. The text should follow the perimeter of the last ring. I can get this done using `arc data`. But since I want to use a variable for the wheelchart and the "title" it needs to be dynamic. This works when I use `{{{{\command...}}}}` (as described in the documentation), but then the text isn’t bended anymore. Is this a general limitation of wheelchart? Is there any other way to get this done?
As an additional feature: it would be great if the radius from the previous wheelchart can be detected automatically so the "title" will be right on top of it.

This is my approach:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart,xstring}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\gdef\exampleforthismanual{%
14/Apricot/Apricot/{A, B, C, E, K}/north east lines/0/0/Gray, 
40/LimeGreen/Lime/{B, C}/grid/0/15/Black,
20/Melon/Melon/{A, C}//0.5/0/none,
16/OliveGreen/Olive/{A, B, E, K}/dots/0/0/none, 
28/Peach/Peach/{A, B, C, E, K}/fivepointed stars/0/0/Lavender, 
32/Plum/Plum/{A, B, C, E, K}/bricks/0/-15/none, 
50/WildStrawberry/Strawberry/{B, C, E, K}//1/0/DarkOrchid%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\getActivity}{m}{%
  \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
    {test}{This is my testing circle}
    {other}{This is an other circle}
  }}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myCircle}{m}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \wheelchart[
  data=,
  ]{\exampleforthismanual}
\wheelchart[
arc around text,
 arc data=|\fontsize{15}{10}\selectfont\bfseries|{{{{\getActivity{\WCvarA}}}}}, %<--- correct text, but not bended
% arc data=|\fontsize{15}{10}\selectfont\bfseries|\WCvarA, % <--- text is bended
arc data pos=0.5,
arc data style={text color = red},
arc pos=1,
data=,
slices style={fill=none},
start half=90,
value=1,
radius={3}{4} % automatic detection?!
]{#1}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\myCircle{test}
\myCircle{other}
\end{document}
```

This is the correct result for having the text bended along the outer ring using

```
arc data=|\fontsize{15}{10}\selectfont\bfseries|\WCvarA,
```

[image]

and this correct regarding the text that should be shown:

```
rc data=|\fontsize{15}{10}\selectfont\bfseries|{{{{\getActivity{\WCvarA}}}}},
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\getActivity` is defined with `\str_case:nn` instead of `\IfStrEqCase`. Then the package `xstring` is not necessary anymore.

Concerning the placement of the title which should follow the perimeter of the last ring: the values for the inner and outer radius of the last ring (which are respectively 2 and 3 initially) can be reused for the placement of the title, combined with the keys `arc data pos` and `arc data sep`. In the answer below, both `\wheelchart` use the key `radius` defined in terms of `\myradius`.

Instead of using a second `\wheelchart` to place the title, the title can also be placed with a `decoration` as shown in `green`.

The keys `arc around text` and `arc pos` are unnecessary in this MWE and were removed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\newcommand{\exampleforthismanual}{%
14/Apricot/Apricot/{A, B, C, E, K}/north east lines/0/0/Gray, 
40/LimeGreen/Lime/{B, C}/grid/0/15/Black,
20/Melon/Melon/{A, C}//0.5/0/none,
16/OliveGreen/Olive/{A, B, E, K}/dots/0/0/none, 
28/Peach/Peach/{A, B, C, E, K}/fivepointed stars/0/0/Lavender, 
32/Plum/Plum/{A, B, C, E, K}/bricks/0/-15/none, 
50/WildStrawberry/Strawberry/{B, C, E, K}//1/0/DarkOrchid%
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \getActivity } { m }
  {
    \str_case:nn {#1}
      {
        { test } { This~is~my~testing~circle }
        { other } { This~is~an~other~circle }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand{\myCircle}{m}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\myradius{2}
\wheelchart[
  data=,
  radius={\myradius}{\myradius+1}
]{\exampleforthismanual}
\wheelchart[
  arc data=|\fontsize{15}{10}\selectfont\bfseries|\getActivity{#1},
  arc data pos=0.5,
  arc data style={text color=red},
  data=,
  radius={\myradius+1}{\myradius+2},
  slices style={fill=none},
  start half=90
]{1}
\path[
  decorate,
  decoration=
    {
      text along path,
      text=|\fontsize{15}{10}\selectfont\bfseries|\getActivity{#1},
      text align=center,
      text color=green
    }
] (270:{\myradius+1}) arc[start angle=270,end angle=-90,radius={\myradius+1}];
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\myCircle{test}
\myCircle{other}
\end{document}
```